# .htaccess redirecting to 404 error

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Problem:
I want to redirect from  `www.domain.com/index.php?mod=daily` to `www.domain.com/daily_rent`

While redirecting from `www.domain.com/advert.php?id=11` to `www.domain.com/advert/11` works fine like this:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} advert\.php\?id=([0-9]+)\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^advert\.php$ http://www.domain.com/advert/%1? [R=301,L]
```

the same rule

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} index\.php\?mod=daily\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ http://www.domain.com/daily_rent? [R=301,L]
```

redirects to `www.domain.com/daily_rent` and throws 404 error. What could be the reason?

**UPD:**
Redirecting from `www.domain.com/index.php?mod=daily` to `www.domain.com/daily_rent` works fine, thanks anubhava

In that case another problem, on similar pages i have more than one query params, like this(example): 
`www.domain.com/?mod=daily&room=1&area=bstn` 
so, i try use that rule

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \?mod=daily&room=([0-9]+)&area=([A-Z]+)\ HTTP/ 
RewriteRule ^$ http://www.domain.com/daily_rent/room/%1/area/%2? [R=301,L] 
RewriteRule ^daily_rent/room/([0-9]+)/area/([A-Z]+)/?$ /?mod=daily&room=$1&area=$2 [QSA,L]
```

what is the solution for that situation? 
Thanks

Comment: Does it throw a 404 when you go directly to `/daily_rent`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you're missing internal rewrite rules. Try these rules:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} advert\.php\?id=([0-9]+)\s
RewriteRule ^advert\.php$ /advert/%1? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} index\.php\?mod=(daily)\s
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ /%1_rent? [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^(daily)_rent/?$ /index.php?mod=$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^advert/([^/]+)/?$ /advert.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: But there is another problem, on similar pages i have more query params, like this: www.domain.com/?mod=daily&param1=a&param2=b
so, i try that rule

`RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \?mod=daily&room=([0-9]+)&area=([A-Z]+)\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^$ http://www.domain.com/daily_rent/room/%1/area/%2? [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^daily_rent/room/([0-9]+)/area/([A-Z]+)/?$ /?mod=daily&room=$1&area=$2 [QSA,L]`

what is the solution for that situation?

Comment: But there is no `area=...` in `www.domain.com/?mod=daily&param1=a&param2=b` do you mean `param1=...` if so your rule will change accordingly.

Comment: yes, sure example url: www.domain.com/?mod=daily&room=1&area=bstn

Comment: Actually `area=` should be right after `mod=` so try just this URI: `/?mod=daily&area=bstn`

Comment: No, this is working example (www.domain.com/?mod=daily&room=1&area=bstn)

Comment: Now that you have totally changed the nature of question it is better to ask this in a new thread by linking this question. SO admins won't like asking a new question via comment section and then long discussions. Let this answer be here, I will respond with my code on your new question.

Answer (score 0):

Surely you want it the other way round - to redirect `/daily_rent` to `/index.php?mod=daily`? That would be a more common usage or mod_rewrite.

```
RewriteRule ^daily_rent$ /index.php?mod=daily [R=301,L]
```

You don't need the `RewriteCond`